# Scrolling of element triggers the full document scrolling on iPhone. How to prevent?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

For example I have a scrollable div somewhere on my site. When the ending is reached then I can't continue scrolling on Android and Windows Phone.

But everything is bad on iPhone. When the ending is reached then the futher scrolling triggers the document scrolling which makes top and bottom panels of Safari to hide. This triggers window.onresize event then. My site looks ugly on iPhone because of this.

How to fix?